# I want to extract a specific section from a json file to python list

Tags: python, json

My Json Code:

```
{ 
"details" : [ {
    "username":"testuser1",
    "name":"User1",
    "code":"50",
    "schoolcode":"100",
    "password":"abcd"
    },
    {
    "username": "testuser2",
    "name": "User2",
    "code": "60",
    "schoolcode": "100",
    "password": "1234"
    }
]
}
```

Python Code:

```
import json

f = open("data.json" ,)
data = json.load(f)
print(data["details"])
```

Output:

```
[{'username': 'testuser1', 'name': 'User1', 'code': '50', 'schoolcode': '100', 'password': 'abcd'}, {'username': 'testuser2', 'name': 'User2', 'code': '60', 'schoolcode': '100', 'password': '1234'}]
```

Here I want to store the usernames in a list using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the list and pick the required attribute

```
data = { 
"details" : [ {
    "username":"testuser1",
    "name":"User1",
    "code":"50",
    "schoolcode":"100",
    "password":"abcd"
    },
    {
    "username": "testuser2",
    "name": "User2",
    "code": "60",
    "schoolcode": "100",
    "password": "1234"
    }
]
}

users = [x['username'] for x in data['details']]
print(users)
```

output

```
['testuser1', 'testuser2']
```

Comment: Also, how do I get all the details of just the first user. Thanks!!

Comment: @DarkSoul, you can read about [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures) in python tutorial to not ask so primitive questions.